# How to send messages in discord without using bot application

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, discord, bots

I want to know how I can send messages in discord, without creating a bot.
Like I want the program to send messages through my own account. Most of the results I got when I searched this up is to create a bot. But I would like to know if there's a way to do it without creating the bot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To access discord with a bot trough your own account, you can't use a discord bot. What you could do, is to automate "your input" in discord. Imagine a google sheet for example and now recording your input to copy the first line, delete it afterwards, then paste it in discord and send the message. now you could repeat this for every line in the file.
(You can find such program using google)

BUT this solution restricts you to your input. Any events discord provides like on_member_join for example aren't useable for this approach. It's more a user bot than a discord bot

Comment: Oh alright thanks a lot! I jus wanted to build something that would farm in Dank Memer, just to experiment.... But the problem was, I don't think Dank Memer would read input from other bots so yeah

Comment: I think so too, but for this such a recording tool should work quite well